# Parse JSON data in variables using JQ

Tags: json, bash, parsing, curl, jq

I have some problems with my script which collects data from a JSON, stores them in variables which are then used for a CURL request. I need to build a CURL request for EACH JSON entry.

My problem is that I would like to pass parameters to the CURL request, one by one.
I was thinking about a for-loop but this won't be actually the right workaround.

This because

```
ruleId=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].ruleId')
```

gives:

```
10055
10098
```

This can not be interpreted correctly from CURL.

So the question is, how can I pass variables in a proper manner, in a sort of iteration, using JQ? Again, I need to do single calls using CURLs for each entry in the JSON file.

Code:

```
$!/bin/sh
#set -e

# Info to test this script
# 1. Start docker 
# 2. Run this command from terminal: docker run -u zap -p 8080:8080 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -port 8080 -config api.disablekey=true -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true
# 2. Get the JSON from api (test for now)
# 3. bash filter.sh
# 4. Check for filter to be set with browser http://localhost:8080/UI/alertFilter/ => view global filter

curl -s 'https://api.npoint.io/c29e3a68be632f73fc22' > whitelist_tmp.json
whitelist="cat whitelist_tmp.json"
listlength=$(jq '. | length' $whitelist)


ruleId=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].ruleId')
alert=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].alertName')
newLevel=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].newLevel')
url=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].url | .[]')
urlIsRegex=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].urlIsRegex')
enabled=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].enabled')
parameter=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].parameter')
evidence=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].evidence')
echo "Setting Rule for: $ruleId"
echo "$(curl --data-urlencode "ruleId=$ruleId" --data-urlencode "newLevel=$newLevel" --data-urlencode "url=$url" --data-urlencode "urlIsRegex=$urlIsRegex" --data-urlencode "enabled=$enabled" --data-urlencode "parameter=$parameter" --data-urlencode "evidence=$evidence" "http://localhost:8090/JSON/alertFilter/action/addGlobalAlertFilter")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash arrays to store your values:

```
ruleId=($($whitelist | jq -r '.[].ruleId'))
alert=($($whitelist | jq -r '.[].alertName'))
...
```

and then iterate over them. Example:

```
for (( i = 0; i < "${#ruleId[@]}"; i++ )); do
  id="${ruleId[i]}"
  al="${alert[i]}"
  ...
  echo "$(curl --data-urlencode "ruleId=$id" ...
done
```

This works if and only if the values returned by your commands are single words (no spaces in them) or they are properly quoted. If you have more complex values you cannot simply assign them to an array with `array=($(command))`. You would get more cells than values in your array.

Comment: jq has an `@sh` formatter. It will do any necessary quoting for you and produce output suitable for assignment to a shell array.

Comment: Is it actually possibile that this solution could affect a next script? For explanation: i'm trying now to run this in Gitlab, pipeline. Running the script using this structure, causes problems to the next script. This, even if there are no dependecies.

Comment: @mdem99 Without knowing what your scripts do and how they interact in your CI setup it is impossible to answer this question, sorry. Open a new question, maybe, with all the needed information about the scripts and your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling the comments from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68726678):

```
whitelist="whitelist_tmp.json"
listlength=$(jq '. | length' "${whitelist}")

mapfile -t rule      < <(jq -r '.[].ruleId'      "${whitelist}")
mapfile -t alert     < <(jq -r '.[].cwalertName' "${whitelist}")
mapfile -t level     < <(jq -r '.[].newLevel'    "${whitelist}")
mapfile -t url       < <(jq -r '.[].url | .[]'   "${whitelist}")
mapfile -t regex     < <(jq -r '.[].urlIsRegex'  "${whitelist}")
mapfile -t parameter < <(jq -r '.[].parameter'   "${whitelist}")
mapfile -t evidence  < <(jq -r '.[].evidence'    "${whitelist}")

for ((i=0; i<${listlength}; i++))
do
    curl ... "${rule[$i]}" ... "${alert[$i]}" ...
done
```

The `mapfile` should maintain embedded white space in values returned by `jq`.

Comment: Interesting solution. Any particular advantage of using mapfile instead of JQ directly?

Comment: I'm a novice with `jq` so can't really answer that question; if `jq` has the option to designate which entry to extract (eg, 1st, 2nd, ... nth) then sure that would work, too ... then again, you're not using such an option in your code so I assumed such an option doesn't exist ... ???

Comment: Actually yes, there is the possibilty to do that but it depends strongly on how your JSON is designed. In my case, the previous solution is really good :)